# how to remove certain elements from array with one foreach php

Tags: php, array-splice

is there a way if I want the code to look like this

```
foreach ($a as $key=>$value) {
    if (( $value['someprop'] == 'some prop' ) || ( $value['someprop'] == 'some other prop' ))
        array_splice($a, $key, 1);
```

because array keys are shifted with array_splice

Comment: Can you please reformulate your question, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: You have split key and value as `$key=>$value` then why `$value['someprop']`? is just `$value` not enough?

Comment: @VijayaSankarN it doesn't look very neat, no. maybe it's an array of arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a for-loop, counting back from the end of the array :

(this way you will not get into trouble with the indexes changing)

```
for($i = count($myArray); $i>0; $i--)
{
    $value = $myArray[$i];
    if (( $value['someprop'] == 'some prop' ) || ( $value['someprop'] == 'some other prop' ))
        array_splice($myArray, $i-1, 1); 
}
```

Comment: I think indexes are from count($a)-1 to 0

Answer (score 1):

Use the more elegant `array_filter` instead:

```
$a = [
    ['someprop' => 'some prop'],
    ['someprop' => 'not some prop'],
    ['someprop' => 'some other prop'],
];
```

Method:

```
$filtered = array_filter($a, function($value) {
    return !($value['someprop'] == 'some prop' || $value['someprop'] == 'some other prop');
});
```

print_r($filtered):

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [someprop] => not some prop
        )

)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: not bad either, i guess this is just one of those "things you need to know" when developing with PHP.